# map app crashes on entering location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-intent

i am working on location base Alarm.I am trying to give some notification when user enters the location.But as soon as i select my current location to see either my app gives some notification or not it just crashes.I want to show notification.
Help!

Logcat file

```
10-01 23:23:23.608: D/dalvikvm(16166): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3395K, 32% free 10967K/16084K, paused 35ms+22ms, total 233ms
10-01 23:23:31.355: D/dalvikvm(16166): GC_CONCURRENT freed 772K, 33% free 10880K/16076K, paused 181ms+7ms, total 480ms
10-01 23:23:34.508: D/HAWAII_EGL(16166): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 16217
10-01 23:23:34.508: D/HAWAII_EGL(16166): eglDestroySurface() surface: 0x40027fc8, android window 0x40027818, Thread: 16217
10-01 23:23:34.879: D/dalvikvm(16166): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
10-01 23:23:34.889: D/AndroidRuntime(16166): Shutting down VM
10-01 23:23:34.889: W/dalvikvm(16166): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e3c930)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.haider.trymap/com.haider.trymap.ProximityActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.haider.trymap.ProximityActivity
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.haider.trymap.ProximityActivity
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
10-01 23:23:34.909: E/AndroidRuntime(16166):    ... 11 more
```

ProximityActivity.java

```
public abstract class ProximityActivity extends Activity {

    String notificationTitle;
    String notificationContent;
    String tickerMessage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

boolean proximity_entering = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING, true);

        if(proximity_entering){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Entering the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notificationTitle="Proximity - Entry";
            notificationContent="Entered the region";
            tickerMessage = "Entered the region";
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exiting the region"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            notificationTitle="Proximity - Exit";
            notificationContent="Exited the region";
            tickerMessage = "Exited the region";

        }

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationView.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("content", notificationContent );

        /** This is needed to make this intent different from its previous intents */
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:/"+ (int)System.currentTimeMillis()));

        /** Creating different tasks for each notification. See the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK */
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        /** Getting the System service NotificationManager */
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /** Configuring notification builder to create a notification */
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentText(notificationContent)
                            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setTicker(tickerMessage)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);                           


        /** Creating a notification from the notification builder */
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

        /** Sending the notification to system. 
         * The first argument ensures that each notification is having a unique id 
         * If two notifications share same notification id, then the last notification replaces the first notification 
         * */
        nManager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

        /** Finishes the execution of this activity */
        finish();


    }
    }
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haider.trymap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <uses-permission android:name="com.haider.trymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />"
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.haider.trymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>



    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"
        />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
         <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBbazKulELXN4QPDM696ix2ENAZAoLHSYY"  />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            </activity>

           <activity
            android:name=".ProximityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.haider.activity.proximity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />            
                </intent-filter>

        </activity>


    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: can you add logcat errors??

Comment: I already added my logcat error file.. see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate abstract classes. Make `ProximityActivity` concrete or make a concrete class that extends it.

Comment: Worked !
superb job !
I added keyword "abstract" by mistake.